# Using more than one ini file with Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, configuration

When starting the application into index.php.

```
$application = new Zend_Application(
APPLICATION_ENV,
APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
```

Is there any way to use more than one ".ini" file within the initialization and also not doing any bootstrap action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inserted this code in my index.php and it seems to work.

```
require_once 'Zend/Config/Ini.php';

$config = new Zend_Config_Ini (APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini', APPLICATION_ENV, array ('allowModifications' => true));
$config->merge (new Zend_Config_Ini (APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/channels.ini'));

$application = new Zend_Application(
        APPLICATION_ENV,
        $config
);
```

Comment: Nice, worker for me too, thanks a lot, and is there a way to access these configurations that are in this files later, when the app is already running?